# Count by multiple criteria not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below table i neeed to count the no.of.triggers that are enabled.

```
TABLE NAME OBJECT TYPE STATUS   
factory     Triggers    ENABLED 
PRODUCT     Packages    ENABLED
REFERE      Triggers    ENABLED
```

In 2007 i tried below but they are not working what i am making mistake in this ?

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D,"Triggers",F:F,"ENABLED")
```

I need a 2003 compatibile formula since COUNTIFS is introducted only in 2007 i tried the below query for 2003 again they also yeileded "0". clearly i am missing some thing here.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D:D="Triggers")*(F:F="ENABLED"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COUNTIFS formula looks OK - if you get zero then it may mean you have some extra characters in those cells, like trailing or leading spaces. What does this give you?

`=COUNTIFS(D:D,"*Triggers*",F:F,"*ENABLED*")`

In Excel 2003 you can use SUMPRODUCT but not with whole columns - you need to restrict the range, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT((D1:D1000="Triggers")*(F1:F1000="ENABLED"))`

That one will work assuming you don't have extra characters in the cells, otherwise try

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Triggers",D1:D1000)+SEARCH("ENABLED",F1:F1000))+0)`

None of the formulas are case-sensistive

Comment: it worked fine but only after i removed all the contents from the sheet & re pasted the data guess there is some thing else messing it. Anyways thnks for the help